# compare 2 arrays and get those variables did not match

Tags: javascript

```
var array1 = ["display1"];
var array2 = ["display1", "display2", "display3"];

  Array.prototype.compare = function(testArr) {
      if (this.length != testArr.length) return false;
      for (var i = 0; i < testArr.length; i++) {
          if (this[i].compare) {
              if (!this[i].compare(testArr[i])) return false;
          }
          if (this[i] !== testArr[i]) return false;
      }
      return true;
  }

  if(!array1.compare(array2)) {
    alert("is not match");
    // get all un-matched variable.
  }else{
    alert("matched");
  }
```

my intetion is to compare 2 array to each other , and get all those un-matched variable out , this code all compare the see if they are matched or not.

how do i get all the un-matched variable ??

so this result will be ["display2", "display3"];

Comment: looks to me like you should copy the longer one and then remove each item of the shorter one from the copy, leaving only uniques.

Comment: Do you need to only compare simple data (number/string) or also object? If object, do you need to compare their data or their reference?

Comment: How would you like to handle the duplicates? `var a = [1,2,3,4]; var b = [1,2,2,3,5];`

Comment: the code is wrong ... `this[i].compare` doesn't make any sense

Comment: please add more examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a temporary object with count the given values of `array1` and `array2` and filter if the value has count 1.

```js
function xxx(a1, a2) {
    var a3 = a1.concat(a2),
        temp = Object.create(null);

    a3.forEach(function (a) {
        temp[a] = (temp[a] || 0) + 1;
    });
    return a3.filter(function (a) {
        return temp[a] === 1;
    });
}

var array1 = ["display1"],
    array2 = ["display1", "display2", "display3"],
    array3 = xxx(array1, array2);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array3, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

ES6

```js
function xxx(a1, a2) {
    var a3 = a1.concat(a2),
        temp = Object.create(null);

    a3.forEach(a => temp[a] = (temp[a] || 0) + 1);
    return a3.filter(a => temp[a] === 1);
}

var array1 = ["display1"],
    array2 = ["display1", "display2", "display3"],
    array3 = xxx(array1, array2);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array3, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: this should not pull unique items from both arrays.

Comment: @nisar, i am not sure, what you mean exactly.

Comment: If I put display10 instead of display1 in first array, then OP should be display10,display2,display3,display1 not display1,display2,display3. I too no sure what the question ? If need to find unique from both array, ur sol is wrong, you picked only first array to compare next one.

Comment: @NinaScholz This only pulls uniques from one array. OP doesn't really specify if they want from just the first array (although their example could be construed to imply it) or if the want uniques from both arrays.

Comment: @NinaScholz Out of curiosity, why `Object.create(null)` rather than `[]`?

Comment: @Ouroborus, it creates an really empty, read *without prototypes*, object.

Comment: @nisar, thanky you for the explanation, please see edit.

Comment: temp[a] = (temp[a] || 0) + 1 what is mean by here? pls explain?

Comment: it evaluates a value `temp[a]` and takes a default value `0` if `temp[a]` is falsey with the logical OR. than add one and assign to `temp[a]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr1 = ["display1"],
    arr2 = ["display10", "display2", "display3"],
    result = [],
    check = function(array1, array2) {
        for (var i in array2) {
            var item = array2[i];
            if (array1.indexOf(item) == -1) {
                result.push(item);
            }
        }
    };
    check(arr1, arr2);
    check(arr2, arr1);
alert(result);
```

Comment: If I put display10 instead of display1 in first array, then OP should be display10,display2,display3,display1 not display1,display2,display3. so this should not pull unique items from both arrays. @Ouroborus

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
  Array.prototype.findDifference = function(testArr) {
  var result = [];

  for (var j = 0; j < this.length; j++){
    if(testArr.indexOf(this[j])){
        result.push(this[j]);
    }
  }

  for (var j = 0; j < testArr.length; j++){
    if(this.indexOf(testArr[j])){
      result.push(testArr[j]);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

var array1 = ["display1", "display10"];
var array2 = ["display1", "display2", "display3"];
var result = array1.findDifference(array2);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter function to separate out the unwanted elements.

```
var array1 = ["display1"];
var array2 = ["display1", "display2", "display3"];

Array.prototype.compare = function(testArr) {
  var difference = []; 
  difference = this.concat(testArr).filter(function(a){ //[1]
    if(this.indexOf(a) === this.lastIndexOf(a)) {
        return a; //[2]
    }
  }.bind(this.concat(testArr)));
  return difference;
}
```

**[1]** this.concat(testArr) = ["display1","display1","display2","display3"];

**[2]** since this is a callback function, it's "this" will point to the global object, hence bind(a.concat(b)); is used to specify "this" to be the combined array.

Answer (score 0):

Functional solution with arrow functions.

```js
var arr1 = ["display1"],
    arr2 = ["display1", "display2", "display3"],
     res = [],
     lut = {};
arr1.forEach(e => lut[e]=true);
res = arr2.filter(e => lut[e] ? false : true);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Well ok the above snippet solves the given example however to generalize the task one can do

```js
var arr1 = ["display1"],
    arr2 = ["display1", "display2", "display3"],
     res = [],
     lut = {};
arr1.length <= arr2.length ? (arr1.forEach(e=> lut[e]=true), res = arr2.filter(e => !lut[e]))
                           : (arr2.forEach(e=> lut[e]=true), res = arr1.filter(e => !lut[e]));

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res,null,2) + "</pre>");
```

Comment: despite the result is not the wanted, you can replace `e => lut[e] ? false : true` with `e => !lut[e]`

Comment: @Nina Scholz what do you mean by "despite the result is not the wanted" ? The result is correct of course however to generalize the functionality, one can store the shorter array in LUT and filter the longer array. Is it that what you mean..?

Comment: please read the comments below my answer. your answer was similar than my answer befor editing.

Comment: @Nina Scholz i haven't seen your non edited version but OK i have attached a generalized version of mine. 10x for reminding the `!lut[e]` though.